# Did emperor Nero have a food taster?

Tags: roman-empire, assassination, ancient-rome

After the Pisonian conspiracy, if would make sense for Nero to have someone test his food for poison before eating it. But I cannot find evidence of food tasters for Roman Emperors.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Quick google for 'food taster Nero gives [Halotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halotus#Halotus)

Comment: D'oh! That's what I get for reading books... THANK YOU!

Comment: Given the fact that (or his mom) he had poisoned Brittanicus to inherit the throne, and later tried to poison his dearest mommy, I'm pretty sure he had a food taster long before the Pisonian plot.